# After killing app, Alarmmanager works on physical device but not on the emulator

Tags: android, service, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make an alarm clock. AlarmManager in my MainActivity is supposed to set an alarm which will be sent to the receiver after the specified time and the receiver would trigger the service. The problem is that when I delete my app from recent it does not work on the emulator but on my phone everything is ok. (There is also some strange this because the app works after being killed on my phone but only if my phone is not connected to my laptop with android studio). My emulated phone is Pixel 2 with API 30 and my real phone is Samsung S9 with API 29.

Here is the part of MainActivity with AlarmManager:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BroadcastReciver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,0);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, pendingIntent);
```

Receiver:

```
public class BroadcastReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("AAAAA","Broadcast");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        intent = new Intent(context,AlarmService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }


}
```

Service:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("AAAAAAA","Service");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alarmclock">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReciver"/>
        <service android:name=".AlarmService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:

I tried starting the emulator without the app and I get those logs:

```
2020-12-27 23:44:45.237 526-553/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
2020-12-27 23:44:45.238 526-553/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2020-12-27 23:44:48.623 191-195/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-12-27 23:44:48.627 191-195/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-12-27 23:44:48.619 191-191/? W/Binder:191_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:288): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup34" dev="sysfs" ino=18285 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2020-12-27 23:44:48.623 191-191/? W/Binder:191_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:289): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup35" dev="sysfs" ino=18345 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2020-12-27 23:44:53.117 526-856/? D/WifiNl80211Manager: Scan result ready event
2020-12-27 23:44:53.117 526-856/? D/WifiNative: Scan result ready event
2020-12-27 23:44:56.060 526-541/? E/JobScheduler.Background: App com.google.android.gms became active but still in NEVER bucket
```

Comment: The problem is not from your code but your emulator. Please a screenshot of the error you get while running it on your emulator

Comment: There is no error or any other info in the logs. It seems like the emulator just stops working as soon as I kill the app

Comment: well I've had a lot of emulator issues before and got them fixed but it always showed error either in the logs or on the emulator screen. I won't be able to handle your issue if you can't see any error

Comment: Ok so I tried opening this app on emulator but not via run app button in android studio but instead of it I swiped up on the home screen to acces all aps on the emulator and chose this one and it seems to be working. Still I have no idea why it breaks when i use run app button in android studio

Comment: Wow that's quite complicated, try running the emulator in Android studio without the app(just the emulator itself) and check the logs. If you see any error, tell me

Comment: I guess there is the problem:E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied  Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
2020-12-27 23:03:44.322 526-553/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver

Comment: Please paste it on your post(not on comments) the exact way it occurred (formatted) I'll attend to it later as it looks more complicated than I thought

Comment: Okay, where exactly did you see the error? Is it on logcat or event log? Because if it's logcat, it doesn't look like an error to me. The normal errors read something like( Java. Lang exception caused by no activity to handle intent) try checking for those type and also check your event log

Comment: Sorry my bad. There is no regular error message but I think those logs say something about the issue. I should have specified that earlier. Again, sorry for my mistake

Comment: No problem, but have you checked the event log tab? (the one at the right bottom)

Comment: I've checked it with and without the app but there's nothing interesting there.